# Submit a form when a video is ended

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Basically I have a form that needs to be submitted in order that the next section of the site appears, in this case it's when a video plays through and ends, the values are submitted via POST so i can't just have a hardcoded URL as i could if i used GET ie. thecycle.ie/test02.php?click='SCENE 09'. The EventListener works but i just can't get it to submit the form.

```
function listen(evnt, elem, func)
        {
            if (elem.addEventListener)
            elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
            else if (elem.attachEvent)
        {
        var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
            return r;
        }
        else window.alert("I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
        }

        listen("ended", document.getElementById("bgvid"), changePage);

        function changePage() {

        document.getElementById('formID').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
        }
```

Below is the full page

```
<form name="formID" id="formID" method="post" action="test02.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="bgstate" name="bgstate" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="vostate" name="vostate" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="choice" name="choice" value="0">

    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
            if(bgAudio) {

                bgAudio.volume = 1.0;
                bgAudio.play();
                }
        }); 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function PlayBG()
                                {
        document.getElementById("bgstate").value = "0";
        var bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
        bgAudio.volume = 1.0;
        bgAudio.play();
                }               
        function StopBG()
            {
        document.getElementById("bgstate").value = "1";
        var bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
                bgAudio.volume = 0.0;
                bgAudio.pause();
                bgAudio.currentTime = 0;
            }
            </script>

    <div id="timeline">
    <!-- top point of ogham -->
    <img src="img/timeline/timeline_start.png" width="31" height="31" id="timeline_01"><br>
    <input name="click" id="timelineButton" type="image" value="SCENE 01" src="img/timeline/timeline_A.png" alt="navigation" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_A_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_A.png'">
    <input name="click" id="timelineButton" type="image" value="SCENE 02" src="img/timeline/timeline_C.png" alt="navigation" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_C_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_C.png'">
    <input name="click" id="timelineButton" type="image" value="SCENE 03" src="img/timeline/timeline_D_on.png" alt="navigation" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_D_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/timeline/timeline_D_on.png'">
    <!-- bottom point of ogham -->
    <img src="img/timeline/timeline_end.png" alt="timeline"><br>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="img/smalllogo.png" alt="the cycle"></a>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="wiki.php?chosenEntry=wiki" target="_blank">Wiki</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="about.php">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="music">
        <img src="img/music.png" alt="music">&nbsp;
        <input type="image" src="img/play.png" alt="play" onclick="PlayBG(); return false;" value="Play" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/play_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/play.png'">
        <input type="image" src="img/stop.png" alt="stop" onclick="StopBG(); return false;" value="Stop" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/stop_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/stop.png'">
    </div>
        </div>      


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PlayVO18()   
            {
            document.getElementById("vostate").value = "0";
            var voAudio = document.getElementById("voiceover_audio18");
            var bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
            var oldBGVolume = bgAudio.volume;
                voAudio.volume = 1.0;
                voAudio.play();
                }
        function StopVO18()
                {
        document.getElementById("vostate").value = "1";
        var voAudio = document.getElementById("voiceover_audio18");
                voAudio.volume = 0.0;
                voAudio.pause();
                voAudio.currentTime = 0;
                        }
                    </script>
        <audio id="voiceover_audio18" class="voiceover_audio" src="audio/vo_balor_07.mp3"></audio>

        <audio id="background_audio" class="background_audio" src="audio/myth_cycle_01.mp3" loop=""></audio>    

        <video autoplay="" poster="img/balorlugh_01.jpg" id="bgvid">

        <source src="vids/balorlugh_01.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="vids/balorlugh_01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div id="decision">
        <div class="container">

        <div class="toggle18">

        <h2>Balor<input type="image" src="img/speech.png" alt="play" onclick="PlayVO18(); return false;" value="Play" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='img/speech_on.png'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='img/speech.png'"></h2>

        <p>You have made a grave mistake, my friend. We will have your hand in the end, even if it takes a few lashings to strengthen your resolve... what is that?</p>
        <br>
        <div class="toggle">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function listen(evnt, elem, func)
            {
            if (elem.addEventListener)
                elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
            else if (elem.attachEvent)
                    {
            var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
                    return r;
                    }
            else window.alert("I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
                }

            listen("ended", document.getElementById("bgvid"), changePage);

            function changePage()
                                {
            document.getElementById('formID').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
                    }
            </script>
            <button type="submit" name="click" id="submit" class="buttons" value="SCENE 09">Skip</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="bgstate" value="SCENE 09">


                </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var menu_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle'),
        menu_length = menu_elements.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < menu_length; i++) 
            {
                menu_elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) 
                    {
        var target = document.querySelector('.container>.' + e.target.classList[0]); // clicked element
        Array.prototype.filter.call(target.parentNode.children, function (siblings) 
            {
        siblings.style.display = 'none'; // hide sibling elements
            });
        target.style.display = 'block'; // show clicked element
            });
        }

        function MakeChoice08()   
            {
                document.getElementById("choice").value = "08";
            }
        function MakeChoice04()   
            {
                document.getElementById("choice").value = "04";
            }
    </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Just offhand I noticed a typo on line 42 in your image tag.

Comment: Is it because it's submitted via JQuery that the PHP doesn't refresh and rebuild the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can`t use "submit" in NAME or ID attribute along with the submit() method, as it will be confused between what it considers an object referenced by the name or id and the method.

Just change `<button type="submit" name="click" id="submit" class="buttons" value="SCENE 09">Skip</button>` to

```
<button type="submit" name="click" id="somethingelse" class="buttons" value="SCENE 09">Skip</button>
```

and `<input type="hidden" id="submit" name="bgstate" value="SCENE 09">` to

```
<input type="hidden" id="somethingelse2" name="bgstate" value="SCENE 09">
```

Comment: Thank you! My god i never thought it was so simple. That was such a headache.